# How inexact is WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

As we know `WorkManager` guarantees execution, but not necessarily in time. So my question is **how inexact is it**?

For instance, a task that I set to be executed every 6 hours (4 times a day), can be executed once a day or even less?

Comment: It depends on the constraints you have used in work manager. If they'll met, then it'll execute the task otherwise not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your Periodic tasks does not have constraints, the only thing that is going to delay it further are the battery optimization like [Doze mode and app stand-by](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

You could expect that your Work will be executed at the first maintenance window, this can be hours out from your scheduled interval, but this is not something that WorkManager can control or change.